# Explainable AI - Traditional ML algos

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In my work, I mostly use traditional algorithms such as Logistic regression, Linear regression, SVM, Naive Bayes, Random Forests, Decision Trees and Boosting etc to analyze data and make predictions.

However, I am encountering some challenges in explain the workings of these to the business users.

Is there any resources or explainable AI methods, visualizations that can help me to explain this algorithms to the business better?

How can I make the workings of these algorithms transparent for the business users to believe the output produced by them?

Can you share any resources that you follow here?

Comment: What aspect of the algorithms are you attempting to explain?

Comment: You may be interested in https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/

Comment: @Adrian - Thanks for the suggestion, it was something I was looking for. at Sycorax - I am trying to explain how a linear algo works